# PING times out after an hour

Tags: c, sockets, raw-sockets

I've a piece of code that implements the ping command as part of a larger code.

Here is the scenario :

1. Run ping with "-c" or "-t" option.
2. Subsequently terminated via Ctrl+C
3. After about an hour I observe that ping fails.

Here is the "socket" call:
 sock = socket(IP_AF_INET, IP_SOCK_RAW, IP_IPPROTO_ICMP);

Before calling recvfrom the socket is set to a timeout value of 1 sec.
When the ping fails I observe that the errno is set to EAGAIN.

I tried some tests and I believe that it is being caused by the sockets not being closed when one presses Ctrl+C.

My question is : What is the problem I can face if I don't close a socket as is the case in the scenario mentioned above?

Comment: Managed to run a few more tests and it appears that the inital diagnosis of ping failaing after an hour is incorrect. Infact ping now dfails if I have 10 ICMP sockets open. The moment I have 10 ICMP sockets open at the same time ping fails with errno EAGAIN.

Now : Is there a limit on the no. of ICMP sockets that one can have open at the same time ??
Also : Is there some way I can reclaim them ??

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-C alone does not close anything -- if your process terminates because of it, the socket is closed the same way it would be if you explicitly closed it.

ICMP sockets are somewhat special, as you can have any number of them listening for the same packets, so even if you did not close them, this does not affect other ICMP sockets.

Engaging my crystal ball, I'd say you are opening lots of sockets, not closing them, and after an hour, run out of file descriptors. Just reuse the one you already have, and close it when you no longer need to ping anyone.

Comment: The ping command being used is implemented as part of a larger system. Thus Ctrl+C just closes that process (the one implementing the command ping). In this scenario do you still think that the sd should be closed? I checked using the command netstat and found out that the sd is still open. But yes when the entire system is restarted the sd's are reclaimed as expected.

Comment: If the fd is still open, then the process still exists -- so either you handle SIGINT yourself, or the signal is not delivered to your process for some reason (disassociated from the session, ...)